# How to solve coupled system of first order ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=A y+B$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-A x$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=C$$

where $A$,$B$,$C$ are real numbers.

> I would like to learn how to solve this system by hand.

Below is an answer produced by Mathematica.

$$x\left(t\right)=D \cos\left(A t\right)+ E \sin\left(A t\right)$$
$$y\left(t\right)=E \cos\left(A t\right)-\frac{B+A D\sin\left(A t\right)}{A}$$
$$z\left(t\right)=C t+F$$

where $D$,$E$,$F$ are real numbers

Comment: The solution to $z$ is more or less obvious. The trick for the other two is to differentiate both sides, then plug in the first order equations into the new ones to get rid of the coupling. For example, you should get $\ddot{x} = -A^2x$ as one such equation. Solve this one first, then plug in to the equation for $y$ instead of solving the $y$ equation directly.

Answer (score 0):

The third equation has no relationship with the other two and can be easily solved. Now take the derivative with respect to $t$ of the first equation: you get
$$x''=Ay'$$
and using the second equation
$$x''=Ay'=-A^2 x$$
Solving this equation (which is a classical second order ODE), putting the explicit expression of $x(t)$ you've found into the second equation and integrating you get the result.